# Authorize.net subscription pending

Tags: magento, authorize.net

I have authorize.net setup correctly - meaning it talks to Magento. I use this subscription extension http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments.html , but when making a subscription through Magento it keeps saying transactions pending on authorize.net? Any ideas? I have tried to do this with test and without - but no matter what it stays in pending.

Answer (score 0):

From **System -> configuration -> payment method** authorize.net configuration **Payment Action** should be "Authorize and Capture"

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I managed to get it up and running.